# AFHTTPRequest result null (even though I can see JSON in browser)

Tags: java, ios, afhttpclient

I am using a GET request to get JSON data.

The call looks like this:

```
-(void)getJSON{

    //Where request is going
    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:1234"]];

    //Parameters
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"GET"
                                                            path:@"/test"
                                                      parameters:nil];

    //Init operation
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    [httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFHTTPRequestOperation class]];

    //Set completion block
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        //Handle response
        NSLog(@"Request succesful");

        NSLog(@"Response: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);


    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        //Code to execute if failed
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];

    //Initiate request
    [operation start];

}
```

When I query on my browser I get this:

```
{"Object 2":"Lemon","Object 1":"Chicken"} //http://localhost:1234/test
```

This response is sent by my method on the server (in java):

```
/**
     * Sends reply back to client
     * @throws Exception
     */
    private void sendResponse() throws Exception{

        HashMap<String, String> mapResponse = new HashMap<String, String>();
        mapResponse.put("Object 1", "Chicken");
        mapResponse.put("Object 2", "Lemon");

        //Convert to JSON
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(mapResponse);

        //write out as JSON
        responseToClient.writeBytes(json);
    }
```

Not sure why xcode isn't handling the response...
When I look at the value in the debugger it says responseObject = x0000000 (null)

[image]

Comment: What's nil? Have you interrogated the operation to get the response / status code / content type?

Comment: if I breakpoint the first NSLog the responseObject has no memory allocated (it says x0000000)=null

Comment: So interrogate the response (operation.response)

Comment: It says <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0xc05ced0>

Comment: That's very informative. In the debugger, type 'p [[operation response] statusCode]', then po [[operation response] allHeaderFields]'. These will give you details about the content of the response...

Comment: error: no known method '-statusCode'; cast the message send to the method's return type
error: 1 errors parsing expression

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31352/discussion-between-wain-and-waf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add HTTP response headers when you send back the data. At least `Content-Type` and, preferably, also include `Content-Length`. This will allow the AF classes to understand what to do with the received data.